# .NET 8 - SHA3 not supported on my platform

Tags: c#, .net

I created a new project on **.NET 8** to try out all the new features. One of them is SHA3, however, SHA3 for some reasons is not supported on my platform. I'm not running it on any virtual machine, I'm on **Windows 11 x64, Processor AMD Ryzen 3 5300U**.

When I try to use any SHA3 class or any Shake algorithm class, I will get an exception telling me that the operation is not supported on my platform. Can I fix it somehow without need of some other external libraries?

```cs
using System.Security.Cryptography;

var hash = SHA3_256.HashData("Example data to hash"u8);
```

```
Unhandled exception. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA3_256.TryHashData(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Span`1 destination, Int32& bytesWritten)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA3_256.HashData(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Span`1 destination)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.SHA3_256.HashData(ReadOnlySpan`1 source)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\admin\source\repos\Net8Test\Net8Test\Program.cs:line 3
```

Thank you.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography#sha-3: ".NET 8 introduced support for the SHA-3 hash algorithms, including SHAKE-128 and SHAKE-256. SHA-3 support is currently supported on Windows 11 build 25324 or later, and Linux with OpenSSL 1.1.1 or later."

Comment: I see, do you know when it will be available for all builds? Or can I upgrade the Windows to that build (I'm on Insider Preview)?

Comment: Perhaps you can use a 3rd party library https://www.nuget.org/packages/SHA3.Net/

Comment: While I don't like 3rd-party library solutions for such small things, then there is no other way to use SHA3 on my platform than 3rd party library. Anyways, thanks for the link and explanation.

Comment: Hm... Same problem here. I've installed the latest Windows 11 updates, but still no SHA3 support (the Windows build is lower than the supporting one). I use Bouncy Castle as fallback, hope there'll be another Windows update for this soon...

Comment: Yeah, I have insider preview and I think I have to be Canary to get the latest support for SHA3, but I still want a stable system, so I will not choose any other insider than preview.