# Using the SHA-3 algorithm in Blazor Server

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, sha, sha-3

I am writing an application that will salt passwords using the SHA-3 algorithm. I am writing the application in C#, .NET 8 technology and Blazor Server. For SHA-3 it uses the SHA3.NET library. As a result, I do not receive a hash, which, given the same set of data, gives a hash in the form: 9uBnQbETH5V7FMDtk-6x, but I receive a hash:��Gc�����_}Hؼ�.&�����1lrh)���$\���r��#����U�#c�. This looks like a coding problem to me, or maybe I'm using the library mentioned incorrectly.

This is a class that uses the mentioned library and returns a string.

```
using SHA3.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace SaltedPasswordGenerator.Crypto
{
    public class SHA3Crypto : IDisposable
    {
        private Sha3 sh;
        public SHA3Crypto()
        {
            sh = Sha3.Sha3512();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            sh = null;
        }

        public string GetHash(string value)
        {
            byte[] val = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
            byte[] hash = sh.ComputeHash(val);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hash);
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone point me to a solution or a direction to go?

Comment: are you using .NET 8 ?

Comment: Yes, it is a problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77501464/net-8-sha3-not-supported-on-my-platform

Comment: Side note, you don't seem to salt the password but hash it. These are different things.

Comment: Mark Baijens, yes I know. It is only part of code. Paramether of the function is password + salt and in this funkction I want to create hash

Comment: Mitch Wheat so SHA-3 is not suported yet of current platform if I correct uderstand

Comment: @Adrian the problem isn't SHA-3, it's the attempt to treat random binary values as if they were a string in a specific codepage. Using `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` is wrong. Hashing returns essentially random values that are *guaranteed* to violate the UTF8 encoding rules. All the hashes you see in hex form actually using BASE64 encoding. Use `return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);`